# How to override last() in django model manager

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

So I have some repeated logic in my django app that I would like to refactor move into the model layer, specifically in the last() method:

I basically want to override last to make it similar to filter, so that I can run query like:

```
Record.objects.last(build_id=1, name="test")
```

and have it return the last record if more than one exist

so it's like combining last and filter into one.

```
class RecordManager(models.Manager):
    def last(self, *args, **kwargs):
    ''' returns last record, logs multiple instances if more than one 
        record exists '''
        try:
            record_queryset =  self.filter(*args, **kwargs)
            record_count = record_queryset.count()
            if record_count > 1:
                logger.debug("{} duplicates for record: {} found for this job. id's: {}".format(record_count, name, record_queryset))
            return record_queryset().order_by('-id')[0]

        except IndexError:
            return None
```

If I run Record.objects.filter(name="jim")
I get back 2 records as expected

If I query Record.objects.last(name="jim")
I am expecting the same results as filter(), but instead I get 60 records returned which is the same as 
Record.objects.all()

Why is last() not filtering my queryset?

I have never messed around with Django's ModelManager's so not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your method definition to

```
def last(self, *args, **kwargs):
    ...
```

Comment: I see that I forgot to add this, but it seems like I am unable to filter with last() . Do I need to manually add the filtering in the last method?

Comment: After your edit: Hm... strange. I do not see any further errors that could be causing it to not be filtering.